# Boost library location on WSL

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just installed Boost on WSL, the includes are all there but CMake fails because `${BOOST_LIBRARIES}` is an empty string :(

Thus the question:

What is the location of library (.so) files after installing `libboost-all-dev` on WSL/Ubuntu? It's definitely *not* in `/usr/lib` nor in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Also `/usr/local/lib` is almost empty except for python distributions.

Answer (score 3):

It should be in /usr/lib.

You can always see where the files are by doing

```
dpkg --listfiles libboost-system1.65-dev  | grep .so$
```

On my system gives

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
```

Note that `libboost-all-dev` is a *meta-package* and will nog contain libs. So see what is contained, use e.g. `apt-cache depends`.

Comment: Wait a sec, so how do I get libs?

Comment: They're in transitive dependencies from the `libboost-dev-all` package (TBH it's all I ever install ("select" is the technical term; If you uninstall the meta-package, you will notice there are a lot of packages "no longer needed", which is because they're now _installed_ but never _selected_). Well, in fairness I build my own boost 90% of the time)